# Javascript charts with live data and scrollable content?

Tags: javascript, charts

I was looking for a solution where I could display live data coming through web sockets or simply by adding items through the console to the data array and when data exceeds lets say 20 points add scrollbar which would scroll data back and forth for analysis.

Can anyone help me and direct to which library is capable of doing that because it's time burning to find the one?

Thank you

Comment: If I understood your issue, you need to make a container scrollable if there are more then 20 records? Is this a web or desktop application? I really don't see a need for an external library.

Comment: It as web application. Ofcourse I could write my own lib just to make it work but I really think there is something already there. I think zooming in and out would also be possible if it had scrollable content option..

Answer (score 3):

Smoothie Charts does offer some live data themes.

We were able to create a demo with a data feed, a scroll bar in [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). One thing you may not have realized yet is that if the data continues to feed, it could be difficult for your users to actually make use of the scroll bar.

In this demo, we added a link that alerts the user the feed is paused, and allows them to restart after they are finished using the scroll bar: http://jsbin.com/mutid/2/edit

I am on the team at ZingChart and I'd be happy to answer any questions about this demo or the library, but I thought that little UX morsel was also useful to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will take a look. Though in my case I'm the user that's gonna use charts and data will stop flowing at some point so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library [Smoothy Charts - A JavaScript Charting Library for Streaming Data](http://smoothiecharts.org/). It is a simple, small and dependency-free library for displaying smooth live time lines.

You may take o look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) as well, even it's not free for commercial use.

If you like to try something from scratch [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com) and [Paperjs](http://paperjs.org/) and just great vector graphics libraries.